# Implementing CRTP and issue with "undefined reference"

Tags: c++, vector, static, crtp

I have the goal to make a base class, and a CRTP subbase class containing a `static vector` that will hold different values for each Derived class. However each object from the derived class must be able to see only one `vector` for the entire class. Moreover, I need to manipulate this `vector` through a common interface, this is why I am setting up a Base class.

Base class and subbase

```
class Seq {
public:
    virtual unsigned long int elem(int i) = 0;
    virtual void print(ostream& os) =0; // print out to a ostream
    virtual int length() const =0;// return size of vector
    virtual ~Seq() {}
protected:
    virtual void gen_elems(int i) = 0; //generates elements
};

template<class T>
class subSeq: public Seq {
public:
    unsigned long int elem(int i);
    void print(ostream& os);
    int length() const {return (int)memory.size();}
    virtual ~subSeq() {}
protected:
    static vector<long int> memory;
    virtual void gen_elems(int i) = 0;
};

template<class T>
void subSeq<T>::print(ostream& os) {
    if((int)memory.size() != 0) {
        cout << "Stored numbers: ";
        for(int i=0; i<(int)memory.size(); i++) {
            os << memory[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    } else {
        cout << "Empty class!!\n";
    }
}

template<class T>
unsigned long int subSeq<T>::elem(int i) {
    if( i>=(int)memory.size() ) gen_elems(i);
    return memory[i];
}
```

One of my derived classes:

```
class Fibonnacci: public subSeq<Fibonnacci> {
public:
    Fibonnacci(int=0);
    ~Fibonnacci() {}
protected:
    void gen_elems(int i); // Gera os elementos da série até o iésimo elemento (protected)
};
```

and its implementation:

```
Fibonnacci::Fibonnacci(int param) { if(param) gen_elems(param); }

void Fibonnacci::gen_elems(int param) {

    for(int i=(int)memory.size(); i<param; i++) {
        if(i>1) memory.push_back((long int)memory[i-1]+memory[i-2]);
        else memory.push_back(1);
    }

}
```

the problem occurs around this line

```
if(i>1) memory.push_back((long int)memory[i-1]+memory[i-2]);
```

compiler yells at me for

```
undefined reference to `subSeq<Fibonnacci>::memory'
```

this has been going on for hours, and since I am new to the concept CRTP, I see I don't understand it well and need help of people more capable than me.

Could someone enlighten me to what the problem is?

Comment: update: if I cut out the static from the CRTP everything Works fine, but then each derived class object will have its own vector memory, and it breaks my goal

Comment: The member `template<> vector<long int> subSeq<Fibonnacci>::memory;` should be defined somewhere. To achieve your desired result, you should do this explicitly yourself in only a single translation unit (cpp file). If you wish to use implicit instantiations, note this answer for more detail on common symbols http://stackoverflow.com/a/16005504/3747990

Comment: cool!
    template<class T> vector<long int> subSeq<T>::memory = {};
works fine, and it seems I achieved the result. I was quite unsure how to define the vector, but it Works. Would you add the comment as an answer or should I do it?

Comment: try using (typename memory) ? It will tell the compiler that memory does exist.

Comment: using typename I wouldn't have to define the static variable somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The member

```
template <>
vector<long int> subSeq<Fibonnacci>::memory;
```

Should be defined somewhere. To achieve your desired result, you should do this explicitly yourself in only a single translation unit (cpp file).

Or alternatively;

```
template <class T>
vector<long int> subSeq<T>::memory = {};
```

As some compilers do support common data folding (e.g COMDAT in msvc) which may help if you wish to use implicit instantiations, note this [answer for more detail on common symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16005504/3747990).

Comment: thanks for the edit. I am not a native english speaker, sometimes I make such awful mistakes. Plus i'm still getting the hang of using stack overflow.

Comment: @GChamon, no problem. Your question had a nice twist to it