# Definition of private weak_ptr in template class

Tags: c++, templates, static

First of all: I am new to C++, so don't judge me. :) 
I tried defining a static weak_ptr in a template class in order to use it over all instances. 
This is my code:

```
template <class T> class my_template : public my_class {

    protected:
        std::shared_ptr<T> sp;

        virtual bool init_impl() {
            sp = wp.lock();
            ...
            return true;
        }

    private:
        static std::weak_ptr<T> wp;
};
```

But compiling gives me the error:

```
.../my_template.hpp:7: undefined reference to 'my_template<my_class2>::wp'
```

Can anyone help? I just don't get it.

Comment: You're only *declaring* the static member, you have to actually define it as well. There are many duplicates here on SO on the very subject.

Comment: Sorry, but I could not find one, where the variable is used directly above the definition. They all define it in a .cpp or something, which does not help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add in the same header:

```
template<class T>
std::weak_ptr<T> my_template<T>::wp;
```

Works for me! :)

Comment: Every source file that uses this header file will get its own copy of the `wp` variable, they will not be shared.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Not true: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229883/static-member-initialization-in-a-class-template

Comment: @DanielePallastrelli: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7109126/65863 - "If you plan on using explicit instantiations in your code, ... then you must not put the templated definition in the header if [the template] is also used in other TUs other than the one containing the explicit instantiation, since **you'd then get multiple definitions**."

Comment: @RemyLebeau: the answer you linked describe another case. Still, it's not true that yout will get one copy per compilation unit.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The code in the answer *is not* an explicit instantiation, so you don't get multiple definitions.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. I thought I tried this before but I must have had a typo somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you do not have a separate .cpp file which you can use to define the storage of your `static` variable.  In which case, you can expose a `static` method that declares its own `static` variable internally:

```
template <class T> class my_template : public my_class {

    protected:
        std::shared_ptr<T> sp;

        virtual bool init_impl() {
            sp = get_wp().lock();
            ...
            return true;
        }

    private:
        static std::weak_ptr<T>& get_wp()
        {
            static std::weak_ptr<T> wp;
            return wp;
        }
};
```

When a variable is declared `static` inside a function, it does not go out of scope when the function exits, it is preserved for subsequent function calls.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I accepted the other one because it is simpler and exactly what I asked for.