# Template function static variable

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template function to give me a unique id based on the `typename` passed to it, like this:

```
template<typename T>
inline std::size_t get_component_type_id() noexcept
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value, "T must be of type Component.");

    static size_t uniqueComponentId{__INTERNAL__::getUniqueComponentId()};

    return uniqueComponentId;
}
```

When I call `get_component_type_id` with `BaseClass` 10 times, I get the same id. That works perfectly.

However, I want to get the same id as well if I pass a child class to that function. When I call it with `ChildClass`, I get a different id. Why is that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should happen to template class static member variables with definition in the .h file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108914/what-should-happen-to-template-class-static-member-variables-with-definition-in)

Answer (score 5):

This is because an instantiation of a template, once instantiated, has nothing to do with a second instantiation of the same template. The two are seperate entities and get their own static variable.

PS: Here is a video where this occurs in an example: [CppCon 2015: Arthur O'Dwyer “Lambdas from First Principles: A Whirlwind Tour of C++"”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXeu4fj3zOs). The example starts aroung 6:00

Answer (score 4):

You can try adding a function that calls `get_component_type_id()` with `Component` as the template argument when the actual `T` is a child of `Component`.

```
template<class T>
auto fn() noexcept
{
    using type = std::conditional_t<std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value, Component, T>;
    return get_component_type_id<type>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`get_component_type_id<BaseClass>` and `get_component_type_id<ChildClass>` are two different functions. Hence, you get two of `static size_t uniqueComponentId`, each with their own value.

**Update, in response to comment by OP**

Yes, it is possible. You could use:

```
template <typename T>
inline std::size_t get_component_type_id(T*, std::false_type) noexcept
{
   static size_t uniqueComponentId{__INTERNAL__::getUniqueComponentId()};
   return uniqueComponentId;
}

inline std::size_t get_component_type_id(BaseClass*, std::true_type) noexcept
{
   static size_t uniqueComponentId{__INTERNAL__::getUniqueComponentId()};
   return uniqueComponentId;
}

template<typename T>
inline std::size_t get_component_type_id() noexcept
{
   static_assert(std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value, "T must be of type Component.");
   return get_component_type_id((T*)nullptr, typename std::is_convertible<T, BaseClass>::type{});
}
```

However, it is fragile. If you want the same behavior for another class derived from `Component`, you will need to make substantial changes.

You will be better off using a `virtual` member function.

```
struct Component
{
   virtual size_t get_type_id() const = 0;
};

struct BaseClass : Component
{
   size_t get_type_id() const
   {
       static size_t uniqueComponentId{__INTERNAL__::getUniqueComponentId()};
       return uniqueComponentId;
   }
};

struct ChildClass : BaseClass {};
```

Now you can implement `size_t get_type_id() const` at any level in the inheritance hierarchy as you see fit.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve what I wanted?