# templated config value class and global list

Tags: c++, templates

Hey there i am trying to implement a simple config value class with a global list which holds these values. 
My implementation looks like this:

```
template <typename Y>
class ConfigSetting;

template <typename T>
class Global {
public:
     static ConfigSetting<T>* head;
     static ConfigSetting<T>* tail;
};

template <typename T>
class ConfigSetting {
public:
    ConfigSetting(const std::string& name, const std::string& synopsis, T initValue) : m_name(name), m_synopsis(synopsis), m_value(initValue)
    {
        this->addToList();
    }

    static ConfigSetting* findSetting(const std::string& name)
    {
        if (Global<T>::head) {
            Global<T> temp = Global<T>::head;
            while (!temp) {
                if (temp->m_name == name) {
                    return Global<T>::head;
                }
                temp = temp->m_next;
            }
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

private:
    void addToList(void)
    {
        if (Global<T>::head) {
            Global<T>::tail->m_next = this;
            Global<T>::tail = this;
        }
        else {
            Global<T>::head = this;
            Global<T>::tail = this; 
        }
    }

    ConfigSetting* m_next;
    const std::string m_name;
    const std::string m_synopsis;
T m_value;
T m_min;
T m_max;
```

Now this compiles fine, but gives me 2 linker errors:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class ConfigSetting<int> * Global<int>::head" (?head@?$Global@H@@2PAV?$ConfigSetting@H@@A)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class ConfigSetting<int> * Global<int>::tail" (?tail@?$Global@H@@2PAV?$ConfigSetting@H@@A)
```

I believe that this has something to do with the kind of circular dependency i created at the top. How can i solve this, or is there a better way doing this with templates? I did not want to create one class for each type i want to support.

Comment: Do you know how to use `static` variables in class ?

Comment: In the `findSetting` function. are you sure you want to return the head of the list when the node you found is `temp`? Also, why use your own list instead of a [standard container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)? In this case, a [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) would be perfect.

Comment: Yes you were right about what i wanted to return.
@P0W: I know that this is thought as a hint, but i sincerely don't see what i am doing wrong...i know how to use static variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linker errors are always the same error: your linker doesn't have the code.
Once you understand that, you will solve linker error much easily :)
in this case, the missing code is the **defeintion of the static variables**.
in your class you **Declare** them, but you didn't **Defined** them.
Here is the syntax of how to **define** static variable of a Class Template:
[Using static variable along with templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607259/using-static-variable-along-with-templates)

I think you got a little messed up with the template classes here (they are a tough part of c++, so don't fill bad about it :)

I think this is what you tried to do:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class ConfigSetting {
public:
    static ConfigSetting* head; // I fixed here, no need for Global, you have this class static vars
    static ConfigSetting* tail;
public:
    ConfigSetting(const std::string& name, const std::string& synopsis, T initValue) : m_name(name), m_synopsis(synopsis), m_value(initValue)
    {
        this->addToList();
    }

    static ConfigSetting* findSetting(const std::string& name)
    {
        if (head) {
            ConfigSetting* temp = head;
            while (!temp) {
                if (temp->m_name == name) {
                    return temp; // I fixed here, you have to return the object you find
                }
                temp = temp->m_next;
            }
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

private:
    void addToList() // no need for 'void' this is C++, not C
    {
        if (head) {
            tail->m_next = this;
            tail = this;
        }
        else {
            head = this;
            tail = this; 
        }
    }

    ConfigSetting* m_next;
    const std::string m_name;
    const std::string m_synopsis;
    T m_value;
    T m_min;
    T m_max;
};

template <typename T>
ConfigSetting<T>* ConfigSetting<T>::head = nullptr;

template <typename T>
ConfigSetting<T>* ConfigSetting<T>::tail = nullptr;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ConfigSetting<int> j("name", "syn", 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define (outside the class) the static `head` and `tail` pointers as

```
   template<typename T>
    ConfigSetting<T>*  Global<T>::tail = nullptr ;
   template<typename T>
    ConfigSetting<T>*  Global<T>::head = nullptr ;
```

Comment: Forgot that i had to do that..Thanks a lot!